# Trigger an event IMMEDIATELY on mouse click, NOT after I let go of the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have probably a dumb question but here we go:

When you trigger a function with onclick="function()" or addEventListener onclick the function gets triggered only AFTER I click AND let go of the mouse.

Is there any way to trigger a function IMMEDIATELY on clicking an html element, NOT after clicking and letting go.

I want this to work anywhere I click on the body element.

Comment: There's a ["mousedown"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) event.

Comment: While `mousedown` has been pointed out, let's think about it logically: since you can drag-and-drop in JS, there *must* be a way to get just the "down" and "up" events. Given that, searching the web for "js mouse down event" would have answered this for you almost immediately. I wouldn't call it a dumb question--but it's a question that can be self-answered relatively easily. *That* is the lesson I'd take away.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know where my mind went. I forgot about this completely. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `click` event is triggered after the entire mouse action has been completed.

Use [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) instead of `click`.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  console.log("You did it!");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check the mousedown event: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp